# on using `handleInApp` WorkoutIntentResponseCode Siri always says "Sorry,you'll need to continue in App" unlike deprecated `continueInApp`

Tags: ios, sirikit

I am trying to integrate Siri WorkOut intent to my app.I am struck with strange error.

```
class StartWorkOutRequestHandling : NSObject, INStartWorkoutIntentHandling {
    func handle(startWorkout intent: INStartWorkoutIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartWorkoutIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        if let _ = intent.workoutName {
            if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 11.0, *) {
                let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "test")
                let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .handleInApp, userActivity: userActivity)
                completion(response);
            }
            else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "test")
                let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: userActivity)
                completion(response)
            }

        }
        else {
            let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .failureNoMatchingWorkout, userActivity: .none)
            completion(response);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in `handle(startWorkout` am checking whether the iOS version is 11 or greater if yes I use `handleInApp` response code if not I use `continueInApp`. This is because

Definition of `public enum INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode : Int {` says

> @available(iOS, introduced: 10.0, deprecated: 11.0, message:
>   "INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp is deprecated on iOS.
>   Please use INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCodeHandleInApp instead")
>       case continueInApp

I understand `.handleInApp` opens the app in background where as `continueInApp` opens the app.

But when I use `handleInApp` and say "Start workout with My AppName" to Siri, Siri Says

> "Sorry,You'll need to continue in the app"

and provides a Open MyApp button. On the other hand if I use simply

```
    func handle(startWorkout intent: INStartWorkoutIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartWorkoutIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    if let _ = intent.workoutName {
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "test")
        let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: userActivity)
        completion(response);
    }
    else {
        let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .failureNoMatchingWorkout, userActivity: .none)
        completion(response);
    }
}
```

Ignoring the warnings Siri opens the App as expected. Whats worth noting though is in both the case

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    //this is a legacy app hence part of code is still in Objective-C
}
```

app delegates method gets called properly.

Though I found a similar question here

[Siri always responds 'Continue in the app' when starting workout with SiriKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571359/siri-always-responds-continue-in-the-app-when-starting-workout-with-sirikit)

but it uses deprecated continueInApp. So cant use it in iOS 11.

What am I making a mistake here? Why using `handleInApp` won't open the app and why Siri complains that I need to continue in App! How to open the app using `handleInApp`.

If I am not supposed to open App from Siri while using Workout intent, I believe there is no way to trigger `IntentUI` also for Workout intent. 
Refer: [SiriKit, How to display response for start Workout Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046532/sirikit-how-to-display-response-for-start-workout-intent)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this one.....

```
func handle(intent: INStartWorkoutIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartWorkoutIntentResponse) -> Void) {

        if let _ = intent.workoutName {
            let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "test")
            let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode(rawValue: 2)!, userActivity: userActivity)
            completion(response);
        }
        else {

            let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode(rawValue: 6)!, userActivity: .none)
            completion(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. Ill have a look and revert back. For now I have upvoted your answer :) +1